# Moving from local development to AWS, node/apache questions

Tags: node.js, apache, amazon-web-services, mamp

All the development I have done has been on my local machine, but I want to now try and host my app on AWS and I am running in to some difficulty.

On my local machine, I store all my code in the htdocs folder, and start my server in the MAMP control panel. I then open up console, navigate to where my node code is and start my server. I can open up my browser and view my web app no problem.

I'm just a bit confused as to how to set this up on AWS. I created an account and moved my files on to the server. I ssh'd in to it and started my node server and it is listening away fine, but when I navigated to the I.P for the server it just says "Cannot GET/". So I then went to start my apache server which I think I did correctly because when I try chkconfig --list httpd I get back

```
    httpd           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

But when I navigate to the IP address it just says

"This web page is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Is there something I should be doing to set up the apache side correctly? Should the files be stored somewhere specific? Can I be running the node and the apache servers on the one server? Do I need to be running both?

My security group settings look like this

```
SSH    TCP    22    0.0.0.0/0

HTTP    TCP    80    0.0.0.0/0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, or if there are any tests you can get me to do to make sure I have set it up properly.

Thank You!

Comment: check your apache logs

Comment: did you start apache? the chkconfig just tells you what run level the server will start, but you have to start it manually the first time you do this.

Comment: Yes I have started it @Mircea. Can you give me more information @Rash? I tried to open my access_log file but it looks blank. What should I be looking for? I just navigated to the folder it is in and "vim" opened it. Would that show me the log?

Comment: what does `service httpd status` say? Rash is right, look in the http *error log*.